# .desktop - run RBENV shell - Run app with ruby version

Tags: ruby, rbenv

Using RBENV on 16.04 sudo environment.

How to use `RBENV shell $rubyversion` or similar solution to run a ruby app from a `.desktop` file for the menu with predefined ruby version?

EDIT:

Heres how i did it with the solution posted by Ḱathryin:
I added interactive shell options to bash, not sure how exactly it works but it helped.

desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=app
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=bash -ic "/path/app.sh;${SHELL:-bash}"
Type=Application
```

The sh exec which runs the app

```
echo '#!/bin/bash -i

cd /...../appdir

source ~/.bashrc
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
rbenv shell 2.4.1
./app $*
' > app.sh
```

sudo ln -s /path/app.sh /usr/local/bin/app

running apps with sudo also appears to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the details of setting up a `.desktop` file, please see: [Creating a .desktop file for a new application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application).

Since `rbenv` (when installed properly) is a function and not an executable, it won't be as simple as pointing to the right file. One solution would be to create a shell script that sets up the environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    # Execute as a bash script
eval "$(rbenv init -)" # Initialize rbenv
ruby $*                # Run the ruby script specified the .desktop file
```

Then make sure the script is executable and put it in your `.desktop` [Exec key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html):

```
Exec=/path/to/script/ruby_stub.sh script_you_want_to_run.rb ARGS
```